# Spring Boot using 2 XA datasources on WebLogic - Oracle - XAER_NOTA : The XID is not valid

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa, xa

I'm having problem with using two XA datasources in Spring Boot application. Firstly, I was unable to use basic datasources because of Spring JPA Hibernate implementation in error log was asking me to use XA datasources, so I switched to XA of this type `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource`. Server is WebLogic 12.2 and database Oracle 12. I'm getting this error (I compund all causes from stacktrace, details are ommited):

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: XA error: XAResource.XAER_NOTA start() failed on resource 'weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource': XAER_NOTA : The XID is not valid
oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24756: transaction does not exist
```

This is my Spring configuration of first datasource:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "my.primary.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory")  
public class PersistencePrimaryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app.datasource.primary")
    public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(primaryDataSourceProperties().getJndiName());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(primaryDataSource())
                .packages("my.primary.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("primaryPU")
                .build();
    }

}
```

And second one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "my.secondary.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory")
public class PersistenceSecondaryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app.datasource.secondary")
    public DataSourceProperties secondaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(secondaryDataSourceProperties().getJndiName());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondaryEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(secondaryDataSource())
                .packages("my.secondary.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("secondaryPU")
                .build();
    }

}
```

In `application.properties`:

```
app.datasource.primary.jndi-name=jdbc/primary
app.datasource.secondary.jndi-name=jdbc/secondary
```

Main class is annotated with `@EnableTransactionManagement`:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```